# Deploying my nextjs project on Vercel gives me the error: "FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key)"

Tags: firebase, next.js, vercel

It gave me this wall of errors during the build:

```
(node:748) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key).
    at createErrorInternal (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/node-esm/index-c327074d.js:466:40)
    at _assert (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/node-esm/index-c327074d.js:470:15)
    at file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/node-esm/index-c327074d.js:5913:13
    at Component.instanceFactory (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/node-esm/index-c327074d.js:5930:11)
    at Provider.getOrInitializeService (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/@firebase/component/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js:290:39)
    at Provider.initialize (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/@firebase/component/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js:234:31)
    at initializeAuth (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/node-esm/index-c327074d.js:584:27)
    at getAuth (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/node-esm/index-c327074d.js:5979:12)
    at /vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/190.js:32:68
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:748) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 13)
(node:748) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
> Build error occurred
Error [FirebaseError]: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key).
    at createErrorInternal (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/node-esm/index-c327074d.js:466:40)
    at _assert (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/node-esm/index-c327074d.js:470:15)
    at file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/node-esm/index-c327074d.js:5913:13
    at Component.instanceFactory (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/node-esm/index-c327074d.js:5930:11)
    at Provider.getOrInitializeService (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/@firebase/component/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js:290:39)
    at Provider.initialize (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/@firebase/component/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js:234:31)
    at initializeAuth (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/node-esm/index-c327074d.js:584:27)
    at getAuth (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/node-esm/index-c327074d.js:5979:12)
    at /vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/190.js:32:68 {
```

I honestly have no idea what I'm looking at. Can someone help me narrow down what might be the problem? Why is the API key invalid when it's working fine locally?

Comment: It depends, your next usage is static or SSR?

Comment: My next app is entirely statically generated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out I just had to add the environment variables to Vercel. Oops.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most common solution with this situation is to create 2 files. First file is .env with keys. Then 'firebase.config.js':

```js
export const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID,
};
```

Finally import and insert object in firebase:

```js
import { firebaseConfig } from './firebase.config';
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Comment: I had the "firebaseConfig" in the main "firebase.tsx" file. I separated the config to a "firebase.config.tsx" file and imported it in the main firebase file as per your recommendation but sadly that didn't solve the issue. The same exact error pops up. :(

Comment: @OmarAlSeddik were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: @Pranav_m7 Yes. Check the accepted answer (the answer I posted).